# Tailwind - Div not taking up full height of screen

Tags: html, css, django, tailwind-css

I am creating a simple login form using **tailwind.css**. I want the form to take up the full height of the screen, but for some reason, it doesn't and leaves white space at the bottom:

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening, but I think it has something to do with the second `div`, which has the `lg:w-1/2` property.

Here is my HTML code (I'm including all of it, just in case my issue has is being caused by another HTML element):

```
<div class="" id="content">
      <section class="relative bg-white overflow-hidden">
        <div class=>
          <nav class="flex justify-between p-6 px-4" data-config-id="toggle-mobile" data-config-target=".navbar-menu"
            data-config-class="hidden" style="background-color: #2A3342 !important;">
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center w-full">
              <div class="w-1/2 xl:w-1/3">
                <a class="block max-w-max" href="{% url 'home' %}">
                  <img class="h-8" src="https://i.ibb.co/LRCrLTF/Screenshot-2022-04-03-140946-removebg-preview.png" alt="LOGO"
                    data-config-id="auto-img-1-2" style="transform: scale(2); padding-left: 30px"> </a>
              </div>
              <div class="w-1/2 xl:w-1/3">
                <ul class="text-slate-400hidden xl:flex xl:justify-center">
                  <li class="mr-12"><a
                      class="text-slate-400 font-medium hover:text-white transition ease-in-out delay-150" href="#"
                      data-config-id="auto-txt-1-2" style=" font-size: 18px">About</a></li>
                  <li class="mr-12"><a
                      class=" text-slate-400   font-medium hover:text-white transition ease-in-out delay-150"
                      href="{% url 'classes' %}" data-config-id="auto-txt-2-2" style=" font-size: 18px">Classes</a></li>
                  <li class="mr-12"><a
                      class=" hover:text-white font-medium text-slate-400 transition ease-in-out delay-150"
                      href="{% url 'resources' %}" data-config-id="auto-txt-3-2" style=" font-size: 18px">Resources</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a class=" hover:text-white  font-medium text-slate-400 transition ease-in-out delay-150" href="#"
                      data-config-id="auto-txt-4-2" style=" font-size: 18px" id = "responsivehide">Upcoming</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="w-1/2 xl:w-1/3">
                <div class="hidden xl:flex items-center justify-end"><a
                    class="inline-block py-2 px-4 mr-2 leading-5 text-slate-400 hover:text-white bg-transparent font-medium rounded-md transition ease-in-out delay-150"
                    href="{% url 'login' %}" data-config-id="auto-txt-5-2" style="font-size: 18px">Log In</a><a
                    class="inline-block py-2 px-4 text-sm leading-5 text-green-50 border-2 border-solid border-green-500 hover:bg-green-500 transition ease-in-out delay-200 font-medium focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md"
                    href="#" data-config-id="auto-txt-6-2" style="font-size: 15px">Sign Up</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-burger self-center xl:hidden">
              <svg width="35" height="35" viewbox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                data-config-id="auto-svg-1-2">
                <rect class="text-slate-400" width="32" height="32" rx="6" fill="currentColor"></rect>
                <path class="text-coolGray-400"
                  d="M7 12H25C25.2652 12 25.5196 11.8946 25.7071 11.7071C25.8946 11.5196 26 11.2652 26 11C26 10.7348 25.8946 10.4804 25.7071 10.2929C25.5196 10.1054 25.2652 10 25 10H7C6.73478 10 6.48043 10.1054 6.29289 10.2929C6.10536 10.4804 6 10.7348 6 11C6 11.2652 6.10536 11.5196 6.29289 11.7071C6.48043 11.8946 6.73478 12 7 12ZM25 15H7C6.73478 15 6.48043 15.1054 6.29289 15.2929C6.10536 15.4804 6 15.7348 6 16C6 16.2652 6.10536 16.5196 6.29289 16.7071C6.48043 16.8946 6.73478 17 7 17H25C25.2652 17 25.5196 16.8946 25.7071 16.7071C25.8946 16.5196 26 16.2652 26 16C26 15.7348 25.8946 15.4804 25.7071 15.2929C25.5196 15.1054 25.2652 15 25 15ZM25 20H7C6.73478 20 6.48043 20.1054 6.29289 20.2929C6.10536 20.4804 6 20.7348 6 21C6 21.2652 6.10536 21.5196 6.29289 21.7071C6.48043 21.8946 6.73478 22 7 22H25C25.2652 22 25.5196 21.8946 25.7071 21.7071C25.8946 21.5196 26 21.2652 26 21C26 20.7348 25.8946 20.4804 25.7071 20.2929C25.5196 20.1054 25.2652 20 25 20Z"
                  fill="currentColor"></path>
              </svg></button>

          </nav>

          <section class="bg-slate-900">
            <div class="flex flex-wrap">
              <div class="pt-7 lg:pt-16 pb-6 w-full lg:w-1/2" >
                <div class="max-w-md mx-auto">
                
                  <div>
                    <div class="mb-7 px-3">
                      <span class="text-gray-400 text-xl ">Join a yoga session today!</span>
                      <h3 class="text-3xl font-bold text-white" style="padding-top: 3%">Login to your account</h3>
                    </div>
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="flex flex-wrap">
                      </div>
                      <label for="username" class = "ml-2 text-green-500">Username:</label>
                      <div class="mb-3 mt-1 flex p-4 mx-2 bg-gray-800 rounded">
                        <input class="w-full text-medium text-gray-50 bg-gray-800 outline-none " id = "username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="ex: username"
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="#d4d4dc" stroke-width="2">
                          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M5.121 17.804A13.937 13.937 0 0112 16c2.5 0 4.847.655 6.879 1.804M15 10a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0zm6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                      <label for="username" class = "ml-2 text-green-500">Password:</label>
                      <div class="mb-6 flex p-4 mx-2 bg-gray-800 rounded mt-1">
                        <input class="w-full text-medium text-gray-50 bg-gray-800 outline-none" type="password" name="password" placeholder="**********">
                        <button>
                          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="#d4d4dc" stroke-width="2">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 15v2m-6 4h12a2 2 0 002-2v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2zm10-10V7a4 4 0 00-8 0v4h8z" />
                          </svg>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="px-3 text-center">
                        <button class="mb-2 w-full py-4 bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 rounded text-sm font-extrabold text-base text-gray-50 transition duration-200 " style="margin-bottom: 7%">Log In!</button>
                        <span class="text-gray-400 text-md ">
                          <span>Don't have an account?</span>
                          <a class="text-green-600 hover:underline" href="#">Create One Today!</a>
                        </span>
                        <p class="mt-16 text-md text-gray-400"><a class="text-green-600" href="#">Please read our</a>   <a class="underline hover:text-gray-500" href="{% url 'privacyPolicy'%}">Privacy Policy</a> and <a class="underline hover:text-gray-500"  href="{% url 'termsOfUse'%}">Terms of Use</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="hidden lg:block relative w-full lg:w-1/2 bg-green-600">
                <div class="absolute bottom-0 inset-x-0 mx-auto mb-12 max-w-xl text-center" style="z-index: 10;">
                  <img class="lg:max-w-xl mx-auto" src="https://shuffle.dev/atis-assets/illustrations/pablo-coming-soon-dark-mono.png" alt="">
                  <h2 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white font-bold">Daily Yoga Quote</h2>
                  <div class="max-w-lg mx-auto">
                    <p class="mb-6 text-gray-50 leading-loose">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque efficitur nisl sodales egestas lobortis.</p>
                  </div>
                  <a class="inline-block py-2 px-6 leading-loose rounded-t-xl rounded-l-xl bg-white hover:bg-gray-500 text-gray-900 hover:text-white transition duration-200 font-bold" href="#">Get Started</a>
                  <div class="mt-12 flex justify-center space-x-3">
                    <button class="p-1 bg-green-500 rounded-full"></button>
                    <button class="p-1 bg-green-500 rounded-full"></button>
                    <button class="p-1 bg-white rounded-full"></button>
                    <button class="p-1 bg-green-500 rounded-full"></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="lg:hidden bg-green-600 w-full">
                <div class="relative w-full">
                  <img class="relative mx-auto max-w-sm mt-4 mb-4 block" src="atis-assets/illustrations/pablo-coming-soon-dark-mono.png" alt="">
                  <div class="flex justify-center space-x-3">
                    <button class="p-1 bg-green-500 rounded-full"></button>
                    <button class="p-1 bg-green-500 rounded-full"></button>
                    <button class="p-1 bg-white rounded-full"></button>
                    <button class="p-1 bg-green-500 rounded-full"></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="py-10 px-3 text-center" style="z-index: 10;">
                  <h2 class="mb-2 text-2xl text-white font-bold">"The daily Yoga quote: "</h2>
                  <p class="mb-6 text-gray-50 leading-loose">test.</p>
                  <a class="py-2 px-6 rounded-t-xl rounded-l-xl rounded-l-xl bg-white hover:bg-gray-500 text-gray-600 hover:text-white transition duration-200 font-bold" href="#">Get Started</a>
                </div>
              </div>          
            </div>
          </section>
```

### Can someone please help me with my problem, so that the form takes up 100% of available screen space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to append the class "h-screen" at the div surrounding both inner divs. it's around line 48 of your markup and has the classes "flex" and "flex-wrap"

make it look like this:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap h-screen">
```